# How to do function on readfile on command prompt in Python (on Windows)

Tags: python-2.7

I use this command on the Linux terminal to perform a function on a file `./pythonfile.py --count ../textfile.txt`
now I use that command on windows on command prompt and it doesn't work.
I use `python pythonfile.py --count ./textfile.txt` to read and count the text after every white space .
When I press enter it gives the error.

error  is : IOError: [Errno 2] NO such file or directory: '--count'

```
import sys 
def cat(filename):
  f=open(filename,'rU')
  text=f.read()
  print text
  f.close()
def main():
  cat(sys.argv[1])
if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: You forgot to post your error message.

Comment: What is `--count` supposed to be? This code would not work anywhere

Comment: I use --count in Linux to call the count fuction... but doesn't understand how to call in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the same error on Linux. You can inspect `sys.argv` with:

```
print(sys.argv)
```

It prints:

```
['pythonfile.py', '--count', './textfile.txt']
```

Use `sys.argv[2]` to get to your file name:

```
def main():
   print(sys.argv)
   cat(sys.argv[2])
```

This should work on Windows too.